# Accounts with open activities

Tags: list-view

I want a list view of Accounts without open Activities at this moment. It isn't possible with a formula field or a roll-up.

Do you have any idea? Is it possible in a report instead?

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with salesforce Reporting feature.

Steps to be followed

1)Create a Report type with accounts and activities
2)Choose Parent with or without having  related activities 
3)Use cross filters in reports to achieve this

https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_cross_filters_create.htm

The problem i see is since activities is lookup you may need trigger to roll the count.Hence reporting with cross filters seems simple  approach for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying your solution. Condition cross object filter: closed (checkbox on activity)= false. It looks good.Which is the problem to roll the count? i don't understand. Thanks again!

Comment: @Enry If relationship was master detail then roll up is easier .Now since its lookup its difficult to get it out of box ,Requires trigger then..